# How to connect to cloud sql from a cloud function and not return a ENOENT error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

First of all I find google's cloud docs lacking and somewhat incorrect a fair bit of the time.

I am attempting to connect from a cloud function to a cloud sql database and I have having endless issues.

Here is the connection error

```
"Internal error looking up Cloud SQL instance "project:region:database/.s.PGS""
Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/project:region:database/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I am able to connect to said database locally with the public ip address and code is all working fine, but when deployed it doesn't work at all.

What I have...

`Project A` - This has the database in `australia-souteast1` region.
`Project B` - This has all the other logic, also in `australia-southeast1`

(the database is legacy, hence why its in a different project).

I have a cloud schedule task that triggers a pubsub, which inturn triggers the cloud function.  This process works, and is logging what it should, this is also where I am seeing the can't connect error.

Connection host is `/cloudsql/projectId:region:database` (coppied from the cloud sql connection page, so I know that isn't the issue).

I have also enabled `Cloud Sql API` and `Cloud Sql Admin Api` on both `Project A` and `Project B` and still no luck.

I have also tried with the default service account by adding the `Cloud Sql Client` permission in `Project B` and then adding Project B's default service account into `Project A` with `Cloud Sql Client` permissions.

Failing that, I then created a new service account in `Project B` and gave it `Owner` permissions and then added that user to `Project A` with `Owner` permissions also, I am still getting this error.

I really have no clue now as to what is going on.

We have app engines on `Project B` connecting to `Project A` without any issues, I am really confused.

Here is the stack driver error
[image: Stack Driver Error]

And my be connection details via an `.env` file
[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Changing the database to a different database instance in `Project A` seems to connect, so it is looking like it is possibly a problem with the database instance.

`Database 1` is working and I can connect to.
`Database 2` is the one that I can not get to work.
`Database 2` is a clone of `Database 1`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the docs are absolutely correct, but you are using the wrong filepath. The unix socket is located at `/cloudsql/project:region:database/.s.PGSQL.5432`, not `/cloudsql/project:region:database/.s.PGS/.s.PGSQL.5432`.

Comment: ah bugger, I actually had a typeo there, i have updated the error.  the cloud sql path i don't include the `.s.PGSQL.5432` at all, i just have `/cloudsql/projectId:region:database`

Comment: Did the error change? You're posted stack still says "Cloud SQL instance "project:region:database/.s.PGS", which still indicates a typo.

Comment: im not adding any of those details to the connection host, i can only assume that it is happening at googles end.  I also have noted that it seems to be only happening on the cloned database.  I also created a new database and imported part of the database to check connection to, and that one works as well. all with the same code, just changing the database host

Comment: i have added some images with the stack driver errors and env file config

Comment: So I can't tell for sure, but you have a very long path for your unix socket. Is it over the unix socket length limit? (>108 characters?)

Comment: ohhh, i didn't even think of that, i will check, thanks @kurtisvg

Comment: well, that did it for sure
if this is the case, and the database instances are limited by unix socket length, shouldn't the instance name be capped when creating an instance in GCP?  Surely I am not the first person to have this issue

Comment: It's a bit of a complicated delima - the file path length is specific to unix sockets on linux, so anyone using TCP doesn't really have to worry about it. As such, it doesn't make sense to limit when only a few places limit the length of the name.